# Are questions from the perspective of management on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

If I am an owner or manager of a workplace, are my question on topic here?

Questions would be like:

- Are bonuses good or bad?
- What should I ask on a workplace benefits survey?

I think that the workplace audience is well suited to answering these questions, even if they aren't managers themselves, but I want to know what the community thinks.

Comment: I wish there was more management participation.

Comment: After participating with the Workplace for a while, I agree with your assessment. Rather than attempt to change the culture of this group, I'm thinking we should have a group for Managers of People: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/76515/managing-people?referrer=MU-waMOyw2gv8GRsyPhc_Q2

Comment: @MikeVanTrufflebutt what does "I agree with your assessment" mean, in light of (a) a question (and highly-upvoted answer) saying "yes, this is on topic" and (b) your proposal for a different site because, you assert, they aren't on-topic here?  Management *is* on-topic here, though of course questions need to be good questions in all other respects too (not bad-subjective, not primarily-opinion-based, answerable, etc).  And yes it would be nice to have more managers asking questions here, but you don't define a site's scope by *who's here now* but by *what topics are welcome*.

Answer (score 19):

Management questions should be on topic.

However:

> Are bonuses good or bad?

is Bad subjective.

What are the benefits and drawback of offering a bonus for X would be on topic though.

Comment: I would expect a question such as that would elaborate, with the title that short only for simplicity. But, point taken. :)

Answer (score 16):

I think that questions from a manager's perspective should be on-topic. They are about the professional working environment, which is the primary focus of this site. However, ultimately, I would encourage questions to be useful to as many people as possible by using wording that generates answers from both employee and management perspectives.

(Also, your example questions probably aren't the best. Both would spark discussion, debate, and/or lists rather than solving a problem.)

Answer (score 10):

I sure hope so.  Asking this audience will probably give you some of the most honest, useful advice you'll get anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

If we were to close all management questions that could also drop questions by team leads, senior developers...

Answer (score 2):

As Adam Rackis hints, I think that for purely utilitarian reasons, it would be a good idea to allow them. It could bring on board a whole load of 'experts' to answer the employee-perspective questions.