# Is project management on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

The question https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/638/is-the-lazy-project-manager-approach-really-as-beneficial-as-the-author-descri is gathering close votes as Off Topic, probably because we have a [Project Management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/) site where the question has a better home.

However, site scopes overlap and just because a question is on topic on one site doesn't mean it's off topic on all others. We've indicated a management perspective is welcome in [Are questions from the perspective of management on topic?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/are-questions-from-the-perspective-of-management-on-topic)

What about project management? When do we draw the line and why?

Answer (score 6):

If the question is strictly about performing project management then It is clearly off topic since that is a specific specialized work function.

We are probably going to have some overlap in dealing with some aspects, i.e. problems with stand-ups, dealing with pm/coworkers, etc.  If the question is like this and clearly belongs in Project Management we should offer them a migration.  If it is unclear then leaving the question where asked is probably the best course of action.

I suspect this question might be rejected there because of its general bad subjective request (is it as good as claimed?) though I can see a version of this question that would be accepted there.