# Line between Workplace and Project Management

Tags: discussion

We had [this question](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/is-project-management-on-topic) in meta a while back about what should go in Workplace and what should go in Project Management. I wanted to bring this back up, as we just received [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/22482/how-to-deal-with-too-many-requirement-changes-which-are-not-documented-at-one-pl). I'm not suggesting that we reopen it, as I do agree with the unrelated close reason, but my question here, again, is where do we draw the line between project management and workplace issues? Would Workplace only have to do with the people management side of projects?

Also, should we put something to this effect in the FAQ, with the small chance a new user will stumble across the FAQ before making his/her first question?

Answer (score 2):

There's no hard line between one site and another. The borders aren't clearly defined, such as when crossing between one country and another; instead, some topics blur a bit and overlap.

[Project Management SE](http://pm.stackexchange.com) is a site for questions in the field of project management. Managing project teams is one thing that is on topic. Thus, it's possible that a question asked here might also fit there and vice-versa.

The question you reference is also on-topic for [Programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) since it's about requirements documentation.  Now, project management is actually considered a field that stands on its own, and a competent project manager should be able to manage a software project, construction project, and other temporary endeavors without having domain knowledge or even getting involved in requirements elicitation.  For instance, one key responsibility of a project manager is to manage the schedule. Scope creep is another project management topic. As such, this question is close to something that would be asked on one of those sites.

However, we don't migrate questions just because they *might* be on-topic somewhere else. If a question is on-topic *here*, then our first loyalty is to our own site. Instead, try to make the question fit our site even more via editing and suggestions in comments.

If a question is closed, we still would only migrate it if it's a shining example of a great Stack Exchange question that's so valuable that it would be a travesty to let it die. These questions are grammatically perfect, represent the best of Stack Exchange, and are something the target site would be happy to have on their site.

For a majority of closed questions, they'll likely remain closed. Posts that are off-topic tend to have other issues. For instance, this particular post is closed as "unclear". Hope this helps!